# Handling multi-dimensional PHP Array

Tags: php

I have arrays of fonts with their name and weight e.g.

```
 print_r($fontarray1);

 Array ( 
   [font] => Open+Sans 
   [weight] => normal 
 )


 print_r($fontarray2);

 Array ( 
   [font] => Open+Sans 
   [weight] => bold 
 )

 print_r($fontarray3);

 Array ( 
   [font] => Lato
   [weight] => bolditalic
 )
```

I have many arrays of fonts $fontarray1, $fontarray2, $fontarray3.. I want to make one final array of fonts and their weights.. for example, if "Open+Sans" is already in the final array, it should not be added, but if "Open+Sans" is in final Array with a different "weight" then only the "weight" should be added alongwith the "Open+Sans" key.. the expected result should be something like:

```
 Array ( 
   [font] => Oen+Sans
   [weight] => Array (
       [0] => normal
       [1] =>bold
   )
   [font] => Lato
   [weight] => Array (
       [0] => bolditalic
   )

 )
```

I tried something like below, but confused on how to add another array within one array..:

```
  $final_arr = Array();
  if (!in_array($fontarray1['font'], $final_arr)) {
    $final_arr []= $fontarray1['font'];

  } else {
    // already in array, lets check font weight
    }
  }
```

any help or thought would be highly appreciated. cheers

Answer (score 0):

First

Use [array_merge](http://www.php.net/array_merge)

```
<?php
$beginning = 'foo';
$end = array(1 => 'bar');
$result = array_merge((array)$beginning, (array)$end);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Second

Use [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look` like structure like this can be usefull for you:

```
 Array( 
   "fontName" => Array(  
     [weight] => Array(
       [0] => "normal"
     )
   )
 )
```

And your function would be like

```
$final_arr = Array();
$fontName = $fontarray1['font'];
$fontWeight = $fontarray1['weight'];
if (!isset($final_arr[$fontName])) {
    $final_arr[$fontName] = array('weight' => $fontWeight);
} else {
    $final_arr[$fontName]['weight'][] = $fontWeight;
}
```

Comment: Thanks misterion.. I tried your code but if I copy and paste the code for second font array after changing the $fontName and $fontWeight variables, I get the following error :  [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: Look`s like your variable is not an array but string.

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to add $fontarray1 to $final_arr?

```
$final_arr[] = $fontarray1
```

Creating a multidimensional array:

```
$theArray = array();
$theArray[] = array('key1'=>'val1', 'key2'=>'val2'); // creates a subarray
```